# Flutter - How to position the DropDownMenuItem below the DropDownMenuButton?

Tags: flutter, drop-down-menu

I’m working with the DropdownButton and I have two questions:

1/ Is it possible to define the height of the DropdownButton Widget ?

2/ How to position the DropDownMenuItem to always start below the DropdownButton frame like this ?

[image: position the item]

Comment: Can you share the code you tried ?

Comment: Hello! Did you find a solution for this?